# windows phone can be set time interval of running in background?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I tired to searching of this question. Every time i search, it also showing that

```
Periodic agents typically run every 30 minutes.
```

`To optimize battery life, periodic agents may be run in alignment with other background processes and therefore the execution time may drift by up to 10 minutes.`

Windows phone app like skype, facebook, Whatsapp. These type of application are running in background and update notification every minute. Why the periodic agent typically run every 30minutes? then how these app to update the notification to alert user in the short period time eg: few minutes?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: They probably use push notifications instead of background agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These applications are using push notifications to update the tiles. This is a message from a web server sent to the phone which the WP7/8 OS processes without the need for the app to run in the background.

Comment: May i ask can we use alarm or reminder schedule to calling process every minute? Its possible?